# How play Audio Samples in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, audio-player, avaudioengine

I'm getting 4096 audio samples using custom function and now I want to play these audio samples in an audio player class.
Can you please suggest me which class would be a better option to play these audio samples in Swift?

Should I use **Audio Engine** for this purpose or **Core Audio** will be used for it?

Comment: I have already worked with AVAudioEngine class and had experience getting audio samples from a microphone or audio file. But in this question, I want to get to know how to play an audio file from existing audio samples.